Нужна ли запятая перед «как» с частицей «не»?
Помогите, пожалуйста, нам с коллегой разобраться.
Предложение: «Это не такое жесткое средство(,) как растительное масло с лимонным соком».
Я, ссылаясь на правило о том, что запятая ставится, «если в основной части предложения имеется указательное слово (так, такой, тот, столь)» (Розенталь), запятую ставлю. Коллега же нашла правило, что если есть частица не, то запятая не ставится. У Розенталя же в примере к данному правилу частица находится сразу же перед как («Я воспитал в себе это чувство праздника не как отдыха и просто средства для дальнейшей борьбы, а как желанной цели».), и я так поняла, что это обязательно должно быть «не как» и частица не может быть где-то далеко перед как, поскольку там также приводились примеры с «совсем как», «почти как», «точь-в-точь как», «именно как». Объясните, пожалуйста, правило поподробнее: это всё-таки обязательно «не как» или частицу и союз могут разделять другие слова?

Правильно:
Это не такое жесткое средство, как растительное масло с лимонным соком.
Пояснение

Здесь у сравнительного оборота трехчастная конструкция:  два предмета (два средства) сравниваются по отношению к признаку (жесткое).

В таких случаях теоретически возможны оба варианта: обособленное сравнение и необособленное обстоятельство. Но этот оборот обособляется в любом случае в силу своей распространенности, ведь необособленный оборот должен занимать позицию одного слова (обстоятельства). Это базовая теория по теме.
 Сравнить: Это средство жесткое как щетка, им 
 лучше не пользоваться. Здесь как щетка в роли 
 обстоятельства степени признака не обособляется 
 (средство очень жесткое).   


Но важно вот что: отрицание НЕ относится к признаку (жесткое или не жесткое), поэтому обособление самого сравнительного оборота не имеет отношения к частице НЕ. Сравнить: Это средство такое же жесткое, как масло с лимонным соком.  Обособление оборота не зависит от отрицания.

Обычно правила регулируют обособление оборота, когда его приходится отличать от обстоятельства. В то же время оборот может входить в более сложные конструкции, как например противопоставление по схеме НЕ...А. Тогда обособления оборота нет:


Я воспитал в себе это чувство праздника не (как отдыха и просто средства для дальнейшей борьбы) /, а (как желанной цели).
Или только с частицей НЕ (противопоставление подразумевается в контексте): Я воспитал в себе это чувство праздника не как отдыха и просто средства для дальнейшей борьбы.
Частица НЕ во всех примерах стоит перед союзом КАК.
 ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ
 Кстати, это общий принцип для всех оборотов речи, 
 которые могут входить в качестве структурных 
 элементов в такие сочетания, как НЕ...А, НИ...НИ, 
 НЕ ТОЛЬКО...НО И. Это касается деепричастных 
 оборотов и однородных придаточных предложений.

ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ (краткая теория для трехчастных сравнительных оборотов). Прияткина А. Ф. Русский язык Синтаксис осложненного предложения. 2016 (основная мысль).
 В общем случае нельзя приравнять сравнительный 
 оборот к определенному члену предложения, так как 
 у него более сложное строение. Но в трехчастных 
 конструкциях с двойными связями (два предмета/ 
 признака сравниваются через действие/состояние) 
 могут проявляться в большей мере:
 — обстоятельственные отношения (предмет 
 действует как?);
 — признаковые/определительные отношения 
 (предмет/признак какой?).

 При обособлении мы подчеркиваем ОПРЕДЕЛИТЕЛЬНОЕ 
 значение, а при отсутствии обособления — 
 ОБСТОЯТЕЛЬСТВЕННОЕ, причем в какой-то мере это 
 зависит от ПОЗИЦИИ оборота в предложении.

Таким образом, при решении учитывается структура предложения и позиция и распространенность оборота.
